# how to fetch an alias

Tags: php, mysql, variables, alias, fetch

How can I fetch an alias from a query to get a result?

The query is:

```
$timecheck = $db->query("SELECT (B <= NOW()) AS var FROM table1 WHERE x='$x'");
```

As a result I need to have:

```
if ($var != 0){
    $updatestatus = $db->query("UPDATE table2 SET abc='1' WHERE x='$x'");
}
```

I learned that I can't use:

```
$var = $db->query("SELECT (B <= NOW()) FROM table1 WHERE x='$x'");
```

That returns the wrong value. So I need to:

```
$db->fetch
```

But I have never worked with that before. As I read through some manuals, I believe it should be like:

```
while ($var=$db->fetch_object($timecheck){
    if ($var === 0){
```

or am I wrong? Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

Before down voting people better should read the query. There is not a simple object from a table which I'm trying to fetch. In the table there is just a timestamp given. I need to fetch the result of the alias. Such a case isn't decribed in a manual so please don't post useless comments like the answer from 'Your Common Sense' and return your downvotes when you don't guess the content of this question.

Comment: Such a case may not be implicitly shown, but it is implied. Try `while ($row=$db->fetch_object($timecheck){
    if ($row->var == 0){`

Comment: i get: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object() in the line: while ($row=$db->fetch_object($timecheck)){

Comment: For Mysqli, try [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). Just remember to `bind_result` and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

> how to fetch an alias

**[exactly](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)** the same way as a regular field.